# How to normalize diagonally movement in player controller?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

When player goes diagonally, he gets much faster. I downloaded a player controller script, didnt write it by myself, so i dont know how to normalize it. Its Realistic FPS Controller by Evolve Games (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLQmJ18f8O4).

Here the code:

```
//by EvolveGames
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace EvolveGames
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Header("PlayerController")]
        [SerializeField] public Transform Camera;
        [SerializeField] public ItemChange Items;
        [SerializeField, Range(1, 10)] public float walkingSpeed = 3.0f;
        [Range(0.1f, 5)] public float CroughSpeed = 1.0f;
        [SerializeField, Range(2, 20)] float RuningSpeed = 4.0f;
        [SerializeField, Range(0, 20)] float jumpSpeed = 6.0f;
        [SerializeField, Range(0.5f, 10)] float lookSpeed = 2.0f;
        [SerializeField, Range(10, 120)] float lookXLimit = 80.0f;
        [Space(20)]
        [Header("Advance")]
        [SerializeField] float RunningFOV = 65.0f;
        [SerializeField] float SpeedToFOV = 4.0f;
        [SerializeField] float CroughHeight = 1.0f;
        [SerializeField] float gravity = 20.0f;
        [SerializeField] float timeToRunning = 2.0f;
        [HideInInspector] public bool canMove = true;
        [HideInInspector] public bool CanRunning = true;

        [Space(20)]
        [Header("Climbing")]
        [SerializeField] bool CanClimbing = true;
        [SerializeField, Range(1, 25)] float Speed = 2f;
        bool isClimbing = false;

        [Space(20)]
        [Header("HandsHide")]
        [SerializeField] bool CanHideDistanceWall = true;
        [SerializeField, Range(0.1f, 5)] float HideDistance = 1.5f;
        [SerializeField] int LayerMaskInt = 1;

        [Space(20)]
        [Header("Input")]
        [SerializeField] KeyCode CroughKey = KeyCode.LeftControl;


        [HideInInspector] public CharacterController characterController;
        [HideInInspector] public Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
        bool isCrough = false;
        float InstallCroughHeight;
        float rotationX = 0;
        [HideInInspector] public bool isRunning = false;
        Vector3 InstallCameraMovement;
        float InstallFOV;
        Camera cam;
        [HideInInspector] public bool Moving;
        [HideInInspector] public float vertical;
        [HideInInspector] public float horizontal;
        [HideInInspector] public float Lookvertical;
        [HideInInspector] public float Lookhorizontal;
        float RunningValue;
        float installGravity;
        bool WallDistance;
        [HideInInspector] public float WalkingValue;
        void Start()
        {
            characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            if (Items == null && GetComponent<ItemChange>()) Items = GetComponent<ItemChange>();
            cam = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
            InstallCroughHeight = characterController.height;
            InstallCameraMovement = Camera.localPosition;
            InstallFOV = cam.fieldOfView;
            RunningValue = RuningSpeed;
            installGravity = gravity;
            WalkingValue = walkingSpeed;
        }

        void Update()
        {
            RaycastHit CroughCheck;
            RaycastHit ObjectCheck;

            if (!characterController.isGrounded && !isClimbing)
            {
                moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
            Vector3 right = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
            isRunning = !isCrough ? CanRunning ? Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) : false : false;
            vertical = canMove ? (isRunning ? RunningValue : WalkingValue) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") : 0;
            horizontal = canMove ? (isRunning ? RunningValue : WalkingValue) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") : 0;
            if (isRunning) RunningValue = Mathf.Lerp(RunningValue, RuningSpeed, timeToRunning * Time.deltaTime);
            else RunningValue = WalkingValue;
            float movementDirectionY = moveDirection.y;
            moveDirection = (forward * vertical) + (right * horizontal);

            //if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && canMove && characterController.isGrounded && !isClimbing)
            //{
            //    moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            //}
            //else
            //{
                moveDirection.y = movementDirectionY;
            //}
            characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
            Moving = horizontal < 0 || vertical < 0 || horizontal > 0 || vertical > 0 ? true : false;

            if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked && canMove)
            {
                Lookvertical = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
                Lookhorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

                rotationX += Lookvertical * lookSpeed;
                rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, -lookXLimit, lookXLimit);
                Camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 0, 0);
                transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, Lookhorizontal * lookSpeed, 0);

                if (isRunning && Moving) cam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(cam.fieldOfView, RunningFOV, SpeedToFOV * Time.deltaTime);
                else cam.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(cam.fieldOfView, InstallFOV, SpeedToFOV * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(CroughKey))
            {
                isCrough = true;
                float Height = Mathf.Lerp(characterController.height, CroughHeight, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
                characterController.height = Height;
                WalkingValue = Mathf.Lerp(WalkingValue, CroughSpeed, 6 * Time.deltaTime);

            }
            else if (!Physics.Raycast(GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up), out CroughCheck, 0.8f, 1))
            {
                if (characterController.height != InstallCroughHeight)
                {
                    isCrough = false;
                    float Height = Mathf.Lerp(characterController.height, InstallCroughHeight, 6 * Time.deltaTime);
                    characterController.height = Height;
                    WalkingValue = Mathf.Lerp(WalkingValue, walkingSpeed, 4 * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            }

            if(WallDistance != Physics.Raycast(GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out ObjectCheck, HideDistance, LayerMaskInt) && CanHideDistanceWall)
            {
                WallDistance = Physics.Raycast(GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out ObjectCheck, HideDistance, LayerMaskInt);
                Items.ani.SetBool("Hide", WallDistance);
                Items.DefiniteHide = WallDistance;
            }
        }

        private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.tag == "Ladder" && CanClimbing)
            { 
                CanRunning = false;
                isClimbing = true;
                WalkingValue /= 2;
                Items.Hide(true);
            }
        }
        private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.tag == "Ladder" && CanClimbing)
            {
                moveDirection = new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Speed * (-Camera.localRotation.x / 1.7f), 0);
            }
        }
        private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.tag == "Ladder" && CanClimbing)
            {
                CanRunning = true;
                isClimbing = false;
                WalkingValue *= 2;
                Items.ani.SetBool("Hide", false);
                Items.Hide(false);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to normalize forward and right in moveDirection, but now player moves too slow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the target is around the `moveDirection = (forward * vertical) + (right * horizontal);`

First, the `vertical` and `horizontal` variables are being multiplied by the Running and Walking values. That is why normalizing the `moveDirection` would make your character slow.

I believe this is how you update the code to fix it. Start by changing these two lines that set the vertical and horizontal speeds.

`vertical = canMove ? Input.GetAxis("Vertical") : 0;`

`horizontal = canMove ? Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") : 0;`

Next, we change how `moveDirection` is set, so the WalkSpeed and RunSpeeds are applied after a normalize.

`moveDirection = (forward * vertical) + (right * horizontal);`

`moveDirection = moveDirection.normalized * (isRunning ? RunningValue : WalkingValue);`

In total, the whole section of code should look like this:

```
Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
Vector3 right = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
isRunning = !isCrough ? CanRunning ? Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) : false : false;
vertical = canMove ? Input.GetAxis("Vertical") : 0;
horizontal = canMove ? Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") : 0;
float movementDirectionY = moveDirection.y;
moveDirection = (forward * vertical) + (right * horizontal);
moveDirection = moveDirection.normalized * (isRunning ? RunningValue : WalkingValue);
if (isRunning) RunningValue = Mathf.Lerp(RunningValue, RuningSpeed, timeToRunning * Time.deltaTime);
else RunningValue = WalkingValue;
```

Any code before or after this block does not need to be changed. If this does not work, please reply with what happened.

Comment: Its worked, but now player moves a bit even after key release

Comment: @vala79 How long after the key release does the player keep moving?

Comment: i guess about half a second

Comment: @vala79 When it moves a bit, does it move at a very small speed, or is the speed the same as when you are holding down a move key?

Comment: speed is the same as when i holding down key

Comment: @vala79 I have edited my answer with the only change I can possibly think of. If this doesn't work, then I don't know why it is doing what it is. Also, can you make sure it wasn't doing this before you used my code?

Comment: Yes, in original script move is smooth, so its just your code. And even with your changes nothing happens.